# Replace string in VBScript/ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have the following string in ASP Classic/VBScript:

```
Y157019=1&Y013759=2&Y032231=5
```

And I would like to modify the string to this:

```
Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019'; Update TABLEX SET Status='2' WHERE Ticket= 'Y013759'; Update TABLEX SET Status='5' WHERE Ticket= 'Y032231';
```

I tried using `Replace()` but could not make it work because the value in the string comes after the name.

Comment: What is `Y157019=1&Y013759=2&Y032231=5`?  That's not a script.

Comment: It is a string I have after a `Request.Form`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `Split()` your string into an array of `key=value` pairs and then further `Split()` the pairs to extract the key and value individually.

For example:

```
Const FIELDS = "Y157019=1&Y013759=2&Y032231=5"

a = Split(FIELDS, "&")
s = ""

For Each kv In a
    If InStr(kv, "=") > 0 Then
        k = Split(kv, "=")(0)
        v = Split(kv, "=")(1)
        s = s & "Update TABLEX SET Status='" & v & "' WHERE Ticket= '" & k & "'; "
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo s
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a RegExp to split your input (sInp) into key value parts and .Replace the those parts into a template (sTmpl) derived from your desired output (sExp):

```
Option Explicit

'                        1       2 3       4 5       6
Dim sInp  : sInp      = "Y157019=1&Y013759=2&Y032231=5"
Dim sExp  : sExp      = "Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019'; Update TABLEX SET Status='2' WHERE Ticket= 'Y013759'; Update TABLEX SET Status='5' WHERE Ticket= 'Y032231';"
Dim sTmpl : sTmpl     = Join(Array( _
              "Update TABLEX SET Status='$2' WHERE Ticket= '$1'" _
            , "Update TABLEX SET Status='$4' WHERE Ticket= '$3'" _
            , "Update TABLEX SET Status='$6' WHERE Ticket= '$5';" _
), "; ")
Dim reRpl : Set reRpl = New RegExp
reRpl.Pattern = "^([^=]+)=(\d+)&([^=]+)=(\d+)&([^=]+)=(\d+)$"
Dim sAct : sAct = reRpl.Replace(sInp, sTmpl)
WScript.Echo sExp
WScript.Echo sAct
WScript.Echo CStr(sAct = sExp)
```

output:

```
cscript 31453580.vbs
Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019'; Update TABLEX SET Status='2' WHERE Ticket= 'Y013759'; Update TABLEX SET Status='5' WHERE Ticket= 'Y032231';
Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019'; Update TABLEX SET Status='2' WHERE Ticket= 'Y013759'; Update TABLEX SET Status='5' WHERE Ticket= 'Y032231';
True
```

**Adapted to the changed specs:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
    "Y157019=1&Y013759=2&Y032231=5" _
  , "Y157019=1&Y013759=2" _
  , "Y157019=1" _
  , "" _
)
Dim reRpl : Set reRpl = New RegExp
reRpl.Global  = True
reRpl.Pattern = "([^=]+)=(\d+)"

Dim sInp
For Each sInp In aTests
    WScript.Echo "----", sInp
    Dim oMts : Set oMts = reRpl.Execute(sInp)
    Dim sAct
    If 0 < oMts.Count Then
        ReDim aTmp(oMTS.Count - 1)
        Dim i
        For i = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
            aTmp(i) = reRpl.Replace(oMTS(i).Value, "Update TABLEX SET Status='$2' WHERE Ticket= '$1'")
        Next
        sAct = Join(aTmp, "; ") & ";"
    Else
        sAct = "no match"
    End If
    WScript.Echo sAct
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 31453580-2.vbs
---- Y157019=1&Y013759=2&Y032231=5
Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019'; Update TABLEX SET Status='2' WHERE Ticket= '&Y013759'; Update TABLEX SET Status='5' WHERE Ticket= '&Y032231';
---- Y157019=1&Y013759=2
Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019'; Update TABLEX SET Status='2' WHERE Ticket= '&Y013759';
---- Y157019=1
Update TABLEX SET Status='1' WHERE Ticket= 'Y157019';
----
no match
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Ekkehard, sorry for not saying it at first. But in my example I have 3 fields, but in the real case could be `0 or N`.

Comment: Nice but what is the point you have to do run it in a `For` loop anyway so the performance gain is lost surely.